# Select options display off-screen in IE

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, internet-explorer-10

I'm testing a new layout in IE 10. When I click the `<select>` elements at the top of the page, the options display so high they go above the top of my window (see attached screenshot).

Is there any way around this using CSS?

[image: Select options display high]

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to believe that this is either an OS-related issue, or an IE issue that isn't fixable through CSS or HTML styles.

When I scroll down the page, thereby raising the position of the `<select>` elements, the list of options appears below the `<select>` element. Its position as shown in the screenshot is too low and MS tries to compensate by displaying the (admittedly) large list above the element, without taking the screen height into consideration.

If I am wrong, I welcome the correction, but I don't think this is something that can be fixed by the developer.